# Mount Network Share to a folder

Tags: windows-7, samba

With `net use` or regular ui "map network drive" I can mount network share to a drive letter (a volume) in Windows. But what if I want to mount it to a folder?

Say to `d:\myUbuntuShares` and not `z:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this question is old, but here is a proper answer for your question. I have only done this on Windows 7 so I have no idea if this will work on any of the other Windows versions.

Open a shell by writing `cmd` in the run field of the start button and enter the following command `mklink /d  C:\path\to\your\directory \\Server\path\to\share`.

You can also do this from powershell but powershell must be started with administrator rights and the command above has to be preceded by `cmd /c`

Comment: yes it's old, but your solution is the correct one. (my bad I didn't put an answer long ago, when I have found it by myself)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Symlinker](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/symlinker-create-symlink-hardlink-and-directory-junction-in-windows/).